# Is there a "Dock" property in java like vb.net?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm practicing with java with graphical interfaces. I am trying to replicate the same design of a program made in vb.net but now I meet a problem. In vb.net there is a property called "Dock" , which manages the positions of the panels and I can make the width / height of the panel that I'm modifying, comes just to the edge of another panel.

For example, see this:
[image]

This is the graphical interface made ​​with vb.net . Everything is perfect, but what about java ?

[image]

As noted , the content panel that have a large image icon excel, is not perfectly seen in the center . (Im using BorderLayout here: *contenido.add(fondo, BorderLayout.CENTER);*)

The status bar should be at the beginning of the line (here I started to use BorderLayout too -*Line_Start*-) but if I do that, I cant see the icon and the text is not fully seen. Clearly, it can be noted that the panels do not respect the " limits " ( or edges ) of the other panels.

As I say again , in vb.net there is a property (Dock) and here in java I cant see it... How is the procedure to ensure that the panels respect the edges of other panels?.

Comment: Alignment of components would depend on their min, max and preferred sizes as well as the layout manager and its settings. From my experience the standard layout managers are a pain to use so you might want to have a look into a more flexible one like [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It looks more complex but you often can create flexible layouts without having to nest layout managers (and components) just to achieve things like putting two buttons at the bottom and having them flow right.

Comment: Wow Thomas! thanks for your comment! This is much easier to use!